# My Question is gone?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I have asked a typical technical question about Microsoft.Ink and the problem that I had with it on StackOverflow a year ago, and now it's gone. I can find it on some other sites that have copied the same question from StackOverflow, but not on StackOverflow itself. It's a bit weird.
Would you please help me find my question (and hopefully its answers) because I need it very urgently?

Here's the duplicate of my question on another site: [Microsoft.Ink RealTimeStylus doesn't work on some computers](http://www.genmaint.com/microsoft-ink-realtimestylus-doesnt-work-on-some-computers.html).

Comment: I have just cast the final vote to reopen this question. HTH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a link to the actual Stack Overflow question:

[Microsoft.Ink RealTimeStylus doesn't work on some computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816836/microsoft-ink-realtimestylus-doesnt-work-on-some-computers) (10k)

It's just listed as deleted with no reason.  `deleted May 14 at 0:31`  It was asked `May 12, 2010` so perhaps it was deleted due to being a year old with no activity at all.  It had no votes, comments (other than your own), answers, or anything else.

I've put in an undelete vote for you if you want to revive that question again, just in case.

Comment: Well I didn't know about the deletion policy of StackOverflow and I couldn't recall if I got any answers or comments.BTW thank you for you kind reply and yes I would like it to be revived again in case that somebody has found a solution for this problem since then.

Answer (score 5):

Questions with lower votes, lower views are automatically delete by system after a year go.

Your questions was with zero votes, and only had 30 views by the time I am writing this.

Comment: I wonder if it incremented from us viewing the page.  I saw it as 30 too but now it shows as 32 views.  :)

Comment: @Jeff, yeah, may be you and me.